# Why it could not insert into table? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

My function store in controller is like this :

```
public function store(CreateUserBankRequest $request)
{
    $param = $request->only('account_name','account_number','bank_id','branch','user_id','status');
    $result = $this->user_service->addUserBank($param);
    if($result)
        $status='success';
    else
        $status = 'failed';
    return redirect('member/profile/setting/account')->with('status',$status);
}
```

My function add user bank in service is like this :

```
public function addUserBank($param)
{
    $param = $param;
    $param['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $param['status'] = 1;
    $result = $this->user_bank_repository->create($param);
}
```

My repository is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Models\UserBank;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Rinvex\Repository\Repositories\EloquentRepository;
class UserBankRepository extends EloquentRepository
{
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->setContainer($container)
            ->setModel(UserBank::class)
            ->setRepositoryId('rinvex.repository.uniqueid');
    }
}
```

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UserBank extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','bank_id','status','account_name','account_number','branch'];
}
```

When executed, it could not insert into table

Whereas when I do this `echo '<pre>';print_r($param);echo '</pre>';die();` before this : `$result = $this->user_bank_repository->create($param);`, The result is like this :

```
Array
(
    [account_name] => hazard
    [account_number] => 123
    [bank_id] => 1
    [branch] => london
    [user_id] => 3
    [status] => 1
)
```

It seem that I am successfully getting the input data. But that was the problem, why it can not be inserted into the table in the database?

Comment: Have enabled debugging option? You are not getting any errors?

Comment: Maybe you are having, foreign key constraint with bank table and there really isn't any data with bank table?

Comment: Also, you are not returning anything from addUserBank function

Comment: @Saravanan Sampathkumar, It's the same. I have enabled debugging. No error. Bank table have data. I had add return. And it's not working

Comment: Can you post your repository file here?

Comment: @Saravanan Sampathkumar, I have post it. What you do not see in my question?